# onFinishInflate() never gets called

Tags: android, android-layout

Who/What calls onFinishInflate()? No matter how I inflate my layout files (in code) this method never seems to get triggered. Can anyone give me an example or tell me when onFinishInflate() actually get called?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`View.onFinishInflate()` is called after a view (and its children) is inflated from XML. Specifically, it is during a call to `LayoutInflater.inflate(...)` that `onFinishInflate()` will be called. Inflation is performed recursively, starting from the root. A view containing children may need to know when its children have finished being inflated. One of the main uses of this callback is for `ViewGroups` to perform special actions once its children are ready.

Let's assume you had a subclass of `View` called `CustomView`, and that it does not internally inflate any layouts itself. If you had a `CustomView` somewhere in your layout, i.e. :

```
...
<com.company.CustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
...
```

You should see a callback to `onFinishInflate()` once it has been inflated. If this is in your main layout of your activity, then you can consider this being after `Activity.setContentView(int)` is called. Internally, this will call `LayoutInflater.inflate(...)`.

Alternatively, if you created an instance of `CustomView` with:

```
...
new CustomView(context);
...
```

...you will not get a call to `onFinishInflate()`. Instantiating it in this way will naturally mean it has no children and hence it does not have to wait for them to be instantiated in the recursive fashion, as in XML inflation.

Comment: So the docs are wrong. If you manually inflate a layout, the callback is not called. But you can still invoke it manually to be homogenous.

Comment: You cannot call the method yourself. It's a protected method... you'll need a protected class. Noticed that having it in the package `android.view` doesn't work.

Comment: That's not true, you can call `super.onFinishInflate` or your overridden `onFinishInflate` in the constructor.

Comment: @GLee What's not true? Only views constructed with xml inflation should be calling `onFinishInflate()`.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer! I am trying to inflate a custom view in a MAUI app which does not have XML but rather have handlers for creating platform-specific views. In my case, it never calls the `onFinishInflate()`.