# What is the use of onFinishInflate() method in View class

Tags: java, android

Can anyone give me a working example to understand what is the use of onFinish inflate method which is in View.

I tried to include it in the MainActivity class by creating as an empty activity in android studio.

```
@Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        if (getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
            System.out.println("Testing......");
        }
    }
```

But i am getting error as cannot resolve method onFinishInflate.

I will be greatly thankful to you if you can further explain what does this onFinishInflate() does and give me a working example to better understand this.

Comment: this is `View` method, not `Activity` method

Comment: thanks pskink but i am new to android so can you guide me by giving some reference or code snippet on how to use this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650906/onfinishinflate-never-gets-called

Comment: @psink .Thanks for suggesting this.But i have one request :--there is no working example there to understand this.Can you give me some simple code snippet to better understand this.

Comment: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.LinearLayout/onFinishInflate